# Design REST-api for posts with microservices

Tags: rest, microservices

I have a sort of "trivial" question about my rest-api for posts but I prefer to get my design right from the start.
Posts can be requested by user, or by google_place_id.
Without a microservice architecture I would choose to design my REST-api like this:

> base_uri/gplaces/:gplaceId/posts
>   base_uri/users/:userId/posts

When using microservices it makes more sense for me to have a microservice "users", "posts" and "gplaces".

In this case, my endpoints would either look like this:

> base_uri/posts/gplaces/:gplaceId
>   base_uri/posts/users/:userId

which doesn't really make sense to me, or:

> base_uri/posts?type=by_place&gplace_id=?
>   base_uri/posts?type=by_user&user_id=?

Preferrably I would use the first option though (the variant gplaces/:gplaceId/posts).

Is there any objection against using another domain as the first path segment in a microservice architecture? (usually base_uri/gplaces would belong to the gplace-api).

Comment: In a REST architecture model the design of URIs is secondary at best as URIs as a whole are just a pointer to invoke further resources. Clients or developers should not interpret such URIs but rely on meaningful link relation names accompanying such URIs. This allows the server to change its internal structure without breaking clients. How you design your URIs is therefore up to you and is therefore highly opinionated IMO.

Answer (score 0):

If each microservice is a standalone service, one each for users, posts, places then I would think the urls would be:

places microservice:

```
base_uri/:gplaceId
```

users microservice:

```
base_uri/:userId
```

posts microservice:

```
base_uri/user/:userId
base_uri/place/:gplaceId
```

considering:

```
?type=by_user&user_id=?
```

type is redundant as you're identifying the type by the second param `user_id` or `gplace_id`. I just think encoding what you need in the uri is more concise

Each microservice has an implicit contract. To return users, places, or posts so any stuff in the url beyond what is required to get that information is irrelevant.